# Returned value is null in the calling method but not in the called method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

This function calls `repository.Fetch(id)` and the return value is always null

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<TVgnItmEstDto>> Fetch1(int id)
    {
        ServiceResponse<TVgnItmEstDto> _response = new();
        var entity = await repository.Fetch(id);

        if (entity == null)   // <============================ Here it is null
        {
            _response.ErrorTitle = "Not Found!";
            _response.ErrorMessage = $"{_vgnItmName} not found";
            _response.Success = false;
            _response.Data = null;
            return _response;
        }

        _response.Success = true;
        _response.Data = mapper.Map<TVgnItmEstDto>(entity);
        _response.SuccessMessage = $"{_vgnItmName} fetched";
        _response.SuccessTitle = "Success!";

        return _response;
    }
```

But when I step inside the `repository.Fetch(id)` function in the debugger, it always has a return value:

See the value is populated:

[image]

What could be causing it to be null in the calling function?

Comment: Can your `vgnItmEst` variable be successfully cast into a `TVgnItmEst` data type? Try replacing the last line of your `Fetch` method with `return (TVgnItmEst)vgItmEst;`. If it doesn't compile or you get a casting runtime error, then that's why the `as` operation returned null.

Comment: `as` will return null if the conversion is not possible, so that might be your problem.

Comment: @gunr2171 You are right. That `as` was the issue. It works when I let it return dynamic, and it is still the correct type so I don't really need to do the cast at all.

Comment: `as` exists for a specific reason. If you're not specifically doing a conditional cast, don't use `as` at all. `as` in C# is like `TryCast` in VB. In VB, you don't use `TryCast` when you actually want the functionality of `DirectCast`. Some people use `as` in C# because they think it makes the code look nicer than a standard cast but that's bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few possibilities for why this might be happening:

1- Try this code:

```
public async override Task<TVgnItmEst> Fetch(int id)
{
    var vgnItmEst = await allVgnItmEsts.FindAsync(id);
    context.Entry(vgnItmEst).Reference(i => i.VgnItm).Load();
    return vgnItmEst;
}

The cast return vgnItmEst as TvgnItmEst; is not needed because vgnItmEst is already an instance of TVgnItmEst.
```

2- Thread Safety: Check if the code is being executed in a multithreaded context. If there are multiple threads accessing the vgnItmEst variable, it's essential to ensure that it is handled in a thread-safe manner. Data loss or inconsistency can occur if multiple threads are modifying the same object simultaneously.

```
Use it with out async & await.
```

3- Change Tracking: If there are any changes made to the vgnItmEst entity or its related entities between the Fetch and Fetch1 methods, it's possible that those changes affect the data or result in a null reference. Ensure that the state of the entity is being maintained correctly during its usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).